# How to moving text from RTL with css?

Tags: html, css, animation, text

I builded a code that I wrote an HTML and CSS.
Here is the code

```css
<style>
        div {

        overflow: hidden; 
    }
        
                @keyframes marquee {
        
        from {transform: translateX(-100%);}
        to {transform: translateX(100%);}
        
    }
    
    
        p {
        
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
        animation-fill-mode: inherit;
        animation-delay: 0s;
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-size: 1.9vw;
      
    }
    </style>
```

```html
<div>
        <p> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." </p>
    </div>
```

The issue with this code is that I want that the text will run at a loop over the time.
And now when the text finishes her animation-duration:25s, stops at once to go back to the start. And it's seems that the  animation-fill-mode: forwards; don't do any effect.
What should I need to do?

Comment: not sure about your animation effect how you want to implement but just have a look at ```marquee``` tag https://www.w3schools.in/html/marquee-tag

Comment: I know this html tag is out of use.. Isn't that right?

Comment: This tag has effect that you might want to implement

Comment: I inserted the tag, but I notice that there is a delay until the text view. So, I looked for an attribute that can reduce the delay but didn't find something. Do you have any suggestions?